# Traer al objeto derivado el operador de asignación de la base (antes de C++11)

Tags: c++, herencia, sobrecarga-de-operadores, c++98

Tengo un código que puede resumirse así:

```
template <typename T>
struct B
{
    B &operator =(const T &) { return *this; }
};

struct D : B<int> {};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Y falla:

> ```
> error: no viable overloaded '='
>    d = 0;
>    ~ ^ ~
> note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const D' for 1st argument
> struct D : B<int> {};
>        ^
> note: candidate function (the implicit move assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'D' for 1st argument
> struct D : B<int> {};
>        ^
> ```

El fallo es fácil de entender: el objeto `D` no tiene el operador de asignación contra `int`, pese a que su clase base sí que lo tiene. A partir de [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) podemos solucionar el problema trayendo al objeto derivado el operador de asignación de la clase base:

```
struct D : B<int> { using B::operator =; /* ¡Fácil solución! */ };
```

Pero estoy trabajando en un proyecto con [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98), así que no puedo usar esa solución. ¿De qué manera se solucionaba este problema antes de C++11?

Comment: ¿No debería ser `struct D : public B<int> {};`?

Comment: El tipo de herencia no influye en el problema.

Comment: Creo que tienes un *typo*. ¿ No será `struct D : B<int> { using B<int>::operator=; };` ? La clase `B` es una plantilla.

Comment: Yo veo que el `using` si compila en C++98 incluso en versiones viejas del compilador https://godbolt.org/z/x96vrG5eP

Answer (score 3):

Basándome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12009901):

Un operador de asignación siempre será ocultado por un operador de asignación implícito o explícito definido en la clase derivada.

> (13.5.3 Assignment) An assignment operator shall be implemented by a non-static member function with exactly one parameter. Because a copy assignment operator operator= is implicitly declared for a class if not declared by the user, a base class assignment operator is always hidden by the copy assignment operator of the derived class.

Puedes consultar el estándar ISO/IEC 14882:1998 y ver que efectivamente dice eso.

En ese mismo documento, en la sección **7.3.3 The using declaration** describe la declaración de `using` que muestras como posible solución. Así que puedes usarla en C++98.

Comment: Por favor, si van a votar negativo díganme por qué lo hicieron. El motivo no me resulta evidente. Es lo que dice el estándar.

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo con el estándar, el único operador que no se hereda es justamente el operador de asignación.

Estás trabajando con C++98, versión antediluviana del lenguaje con muchas menos ayudas que las versiones más recientes.

¿Soluciones?

Puedes implementar el operador de asignación en la clase derivada y hacer que dicha versión llame al operador de la clase base:

```
struct D : B<int> {
    D& operator=(const int& value)
    { 
        static_cast<B<int>&>(*this) = value;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

O, si prefieres dejarlo en una sola línea:

```
D& operator=(const int& value)
{
    return static_cast<D&>(static_cast<B<int>&>(*this) = value);
}
```